# Processing text file contents > launching separate bat instances [Windows Batch]

Tags: windows, batch-file

Say foo.txt contains the following:

A

B

C

I have two batch files, one to read the contents of foo.txt and the second to process said contents.  How to I go about processing the content of each line in foo.txt in 1.bat to run in 2.bat?  1.bat reads in foo.txt and results in running (in separate instances):

2.bat A

2.bat B

2.bat C

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of 1.bat and 2.bat?  You can use something like `FOR /f "delims=" %%a in (foo.txt) do 2.bat %%a` to call 2.bat for each line.

Comment: I tried something similar before but it ended on the first item.  For example,

Comment: I tried something similar before but it ended on the first item.  For example, 1.bat had your code and GOTO end underneath it and 2.bat ran with A, but since 2.bat had a loop in it, 2.bat didn't end (on purpose), thus the B value never reached 2.bat.  The temporary solution so far is to  use the following in 1.bat: ```start /min cmd /c 2.bat A```.  Too bad I can't simply add or subtract values in foo.txt and have it launch immediately a single instance of 2.bat for every value stored in foo.txt upon running 1.bat.

Comment: I understand now.  You are looking for the [`CALL`](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html) command.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over the lines of a file, you can use `FOR /F`.  The following will read each line of `foo.txt` and do something with it. (in this case, simply print with equal signs around it)

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (foo.txt) do ( echo === %%a === )
```

The `delims` part tells FOR to put the whole line into %a.  By default it will split into multiple variables if the file contains tabs.

When you run a batch file from another batch file, CMD's default action is to terminate the first script and launch the second.

```
echo This line prints
2.bat
echo This line never runs because the script was terminated.
```

To call another batch file from your file, returning to the first when it is completed, use the **CALL** command.

```
echo Try again...
call 2.bat
echo This line runs as expected.
```

Combining `FOR` and `CALL`, the following will call 2.bat once for each line in foo.txt

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (foo.txt) do call 2.bat %%a
```